# prepareForSegue method not showing correct data when passed to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue, pfquery

On my app when I click on the cell, data passes to the next view controller. The data gets passed and displayed when I segue using my prepareForSegue method from my PFQueryTableViewController, however it does not segue the correct data. For example if I click on the cell that says "John Smith", the next page shows a different name that comes from Parse. How do I show the correct data passed when segueing to the next view controller?

Here is my FirstViewController with the prepareForSegue:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showReplyViewController", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "showReplyViewController") {

      let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
      let obj = self.objects![indexPath!.row] as! PFObject

      let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ReplyViewController
      destinationVC.commentPost = obj

    }
}
```

Here is my SecondViewController where I load the data:

```
var commentPost = PFObject(className: "GlamTest")
func headerCellAtIndexPath() -> HeaderTableViewCell {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell

    headerCell.headerUsernameLabel.text = commentPost.objectForKey("Name") as? String ?? "nil"

    headerCell.headerMessageLabel.text = commentPost.objectForKey("userMessage") as? String ?? "nil"

    return headerCell

}
```

Comment: The approach you show here is impeccable.  The only explanation I can suggest for why you're seeing a disconnect between the selected cell and the detail vc would be if your cellForRowAtIndexPath method accesses the array differently than `let obj = self.objects![indexPath!.row] as! PFObject` as it does in prepare for segue.

Comment: the cellForRowAtIndexPath method accesses the array something like:

if let userPost : PFObject = self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as? PFObject {
…
}
return cell
}

Comment: Ah, see that?  Does `self.posts` contain exactly the same elements as `self.objects`?  If not, then you'll get one thing in the cell and a different thing in the destination view controller.  Try accessing the very same array in the very same way in all of your datasource related methods.